# Are gas distribution networks tree-like?

Tags: civil-engineering, modeling, mathematics, gas, infrastructure

I was wondering, if it is justified to say, that gas distribution network graphs (primarily in Europe) are typically tree-like. By gas distribution networks I mean municipal and regional distribution networks, not the long-range transport networks.
To me, it would seem reasonable, since alternation of flow direction makes little sense, given that there are few sources and mostly sinks in the network and establishing circular flows would be a waste of energy. Does anyone have experience with that?

Cheers,
Tobi

Comment: Will different suppliers be like different tree species?

Comment: @SolarMike At least in the UK, supply companies and distribution companies are separate entities (even if they are both subsidiaries of the same parent). Just like electricity distribution, your gas supplier is actually selling you heat energy, not their "own" methane molecules or electrons.

Comment: @alephzero, but here in Ireland I never get any electrons from my supplier. They just push mine back and forward.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your comments. I am familiar with the general structure of gas network infrastructure, since I am involved in gas network modeling. I was hoping for some industry expertise on the distribution grid structure since data is hard to get.
@Transistor That last comment made me chuckle ;)